# TypeError: tuple - tuple on keras custom error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to make a custom loss function that compares gradient between two images, using Keras. So I made a code like:

```
def mean_gradient_error(y_true,y_pred):
    alpha = 0.6
    if not B.is_tensor(y_pred):
        y_pred = B.constant(y_pred)
    y_true = B.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
    yt_grad = B_.tf.image.image_gradients(y_true)
    yp_grad = B_.tf.image.image_gradients(y_pred)
    dotprod = B.mean(1-B.sum(y_pred*y_true,axis=-1))
    grad_diff = (yt_grad-yp_grad)
    gerr = B.mean(grad_diff**2,axis=-1)
    return (1-alpha)*dotprod+alpha*gerr
```

Here dotprod worked well, but grad_diff put out error message like :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

I think keras says that I should change the type of yp_grad and yt_grad, but I'm not getting how I should.

Which code should I add ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`tf.image.image_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/image_gradients) states :

> **Returns**
> Pair of tensors (dy, dx) holding the vertical and horizontal image gradients (1-step finite difference).

This function returns a tuple. You can't subtract tuples.

One possibility is to compute the diff for x and y, and then sum the two errors.

```
yt_grad = B_.tf.image.image_gradients(y_true)
yp_grad = B_.tf.image.image_gradients(y_pred)
grad_diff_x = (yt_grad[0]-yp_grad[0])
grad_diff_y = (yt_grad[1]-yp_grad[1])
gerr = B.mean(grad_diff_x**2,axis=-1) + B.mean(grad_diff_y**2,axis=-1)
```